# Novel translation help

Tags: translation

I am translating a light novel from Korean and having trouble understanding the reference in the following exchange. This is between two people who are fighting. The setting is inside of a video game, so one character (MC) has just used stat points to increase their strength and speed.

MC: “Don’t go에 힘 빡 줘라.”

“돈고?”

MC: “똥꼬, 새꺄.”

아주 지리게 만들어 주마.

Right now, I have it translated as:

"Put all your strength into 'Don't go.'"

"Dongo?"

"You shitty bastard."

I'll make you pay dearly.

But I don't understand the "Put all your strength into 'Don't go'." line. I understand that the MC is saying "Don't go" in English and the other person is confused because they don't speak English. But why would he say "put all your strength into 'don't go'"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a vulgar pun: "Don't go" sounds similar to the Korean word, 똥꼬, which is a slang (or baby-talk) for butthole.

The the first guy is saying "Clench your butthole", and then "I'm going to make you shit yourself."

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you. I would have never gotten that!